# Cannot change width of element for print media

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing

Assume two columns positioned side by side in the screen media. Both columns have `transition: width .1s;` (any delay can fit). Now the task is to change their width for print media. As of Google Chrome v35 I had to use workarounds to make it possible.

Let me show you an example (you can check live example instead: http://jsbin.com/faxow )

**HTML**:

```
<div class="column eight">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="column four">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.column { float: left; transition: width .1s; }

.eight { width: 66.66667%; }
.four { width: 33.33333%; }

@media print {
  .eight, .four { width: 100%; }
}
```

This will not apply `width: 100%` to columns in print media in Google Chrome (at least v35) unless I either:

- move `transition: width .1s` to `@media screen {}` scope
- get rid of `transition: width .1s` entirely
- use an `alert()` inside `window.matchMedia('print')` listener with Javascript

Is there a special reason for that? Is it an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

It's because at @media print, browser can't interpret the transition codes.
you can simply solve the problem by adding this:

```
@media print {
  * {
    transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. It looks even more elegant than the one I came up with (scoping transitions inside @media screen). But it's a bit not what I ask. I'd like to know why this happens to Chrome and not to other browsers and what is the correct behavior, I couldn't find any spec on this in W3C btw. Any thoughts? I appreciate your answer though, I'm sure it will be helpful to many in the future.